# '<=' not supported between instances of 'int' and 'builtin_function_or_method' for Array based on CSV file

Tags: python-3.x, scikit-learn

my code isn't working and I don't know how to define a `CSV` file as an integer as an `Array`. Any help will be greatly appreciated. I am still a beginner.

The error comes up on line 17 '`fit = bestfeatures.fit(X,Y)`'

```
import pandas as pd
from matplotlib import pyplot
import seaborn as sns
from sklearn.feature_selection import SelectKBest
from sklearn.feature_selection import chi2
from sklearn.datasets import load_digits
from pandas import read_csv
from pandas.plotting import scatter_matrix


filename = '/Users/rahulparmeshwar/Documents/Algo Bots/Data/Live Data/Tester.csv'
data = read_csv(filename)

bestfeatures = SelectKBest(k=all)
y = data['Vol']
X = data.drop('Open',axis=1)
fit = bestfeatures.fit(X,y)
dfscores = pd.DataFrame(fit.scores_)
dfcolumns = pd.DataFrame(X.columns)
featurescores = pd.concat([dfscores,dfcolumns],axis=1)
correlation = data.corr()
print(featurescores.nlargest(2,'Score'))

pd.set_option('display.width',100)
data.head(1)
print(data)

scatter_matrix(data)
pyplot.show()
```

Comment: Always include the whole error message in the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`SelectKBest(k=all)` must be `SelectKBest(k="all")`. `all()` is a built-in function. `"all"` is a string.